# Updating mysql database cause a error

Tags: c#, mysql

I was trying to update my mysql database but it didn't work and showed me error.

The code :

```
string constring = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=root";
string Query = "update  database.check set  namethestore = '" + this.textBox65.Text + "' , checkername= '" + this.textBox66.Text + "' ,  where namethestore = '" + this.textBox65.Text + "'  ;";
MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
MySqlDataReader myReader;
try
{
   conDataBase.Open();
   myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();
   MessageBox.Show("saved");

   while (myReader.Read())
   {
   }
```

Comment: What error you getting?

Comment: You are exposed to SQL Injection. Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: @user3806048 You build an `UPDATE` statement - and then try a reader on this statement. I think you should use the `ExecuteNonQuery()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a extra `,` in your `UPDATE` statement before `WHERE` condition as below

```
update  database.check set  namethestore = '" + this.textBox65.Text + "' , 
checkername= '" + this.textBox66.Text + "' ,  where ...;

                                           <--Here
```

As other's have already commented, your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection. Try using a parametrized query rather.

Also, since you are performing a DML operation, no need of a `DataReader`. You can either use `ExecuteNonQuery` or `ExecuteScalar`.

For your reference:

```
string constring = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=root";
string Query = "update  database.check set  namethestore = 
@namethestore,checkername=@checkername where namethestore = @namethestore";
using(MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring))
{
  using(MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase))
   {
     conDataBase.Open();
     cmdDataBase.CommandText = Query;
     cmdDataBase.Parameters.Add("@namethestore", this.textBox65.Text);
     cmdDataBase.Parameters.Add("@checkername", this.textBox66.Text);

     cmdDataBase.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by @namethstore ? , do you mean the name of the textbox like texbox1.txt ?

Comment: @user3806048 These are placeholders for your values.

Comment: @user3806048, No those are parameters which going to hold the value of textbox. You pass those parameters to your SQL query. This avoids SQL injection attack. Read more in MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.

Comment: i did as you asked but i still go error , my code : 
            string Query = "update  database.check set  namethestore = '" + this.textBox65.Text + "' , checkername= '" + this.textBox66.Text + "'  where namethestore = '" + this.textBox65.Text + "' :";
using(MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring))
{

Comment: using(MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase))
   {
     conDataBase.Open();
     cmdDataBase.CommandText = Query;
     cmdDataBase.Parameters.Add("+ this.textBox65.Text +", this.textBox65.Text);
     cmdDataBase.Parameters.Add(" + this.textBox66.Text +", this.textBox66.Text);

     cmdDataBase.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }

Comment: @user3806048, that's not at all what I suggested in my answer. You don't use parameter that way. I have posted the code in my answer. If needed you can directly copy/paste it and use it. I have provided MSDN doc link in another comment. Read the document to understand command parameter better before you use it.

Answer (score 1):

There are so many things wrong on that code.

1. You should use ExecuteNonQuery to an update statement
2. You must use parameterised query to protect your code from SQL Injection
3. AS Rahul said, you have an extra ,
4. I would like to know if you are closing the connection at the end.

Answer (score 0):

[`ExecuteReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns a  `MySqlDataReader` which contains the result of your `MySqlCommand`. Since you use `INSERT` statement, there is no data your statement that return. Your statement is just insert a value from your database.

That's why you should use [`ExecuteNonQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It just executes your statement and for `INSERT` statement, it returns that the number of rows affected.

And you should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Also use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your database connections.

And you have an extra comma (`,`) before your `WHERE` condition.

```
using(MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(constring))
using(MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = "update database.check set namethestore = @namethestore, checkername= @checkername where namethestore = @namethestore";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@namethestore, this.textBox66.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@checkername, this.textBox65.Text);
    conn.Open()
    if(cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
       MessageBox.Show("saved");
}
```

I used `AddWithValue` in my example because I don't know your column types but **you don't use it.** Use [`SqlParameterCollection.Add` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.

Read http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/